# converting base64 string to a jpg file php

Tags: php

I have received a base 64 string of an image in my PHP code, I am then trying to convert this string and write it to a jpg file. However, it's not converting it correctly and won't let me write it as a jpg and gives me this error.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$response = 0;

if (isset($_POST['Image'])) {

    "include connection.php";
    $image = urldecode($_POST["Image"]);
    $content = base64_decode($image);


    $file = fopen("unknown.jpg", "wb");
    fwrite($file, $content);
    fclose($file);

    //$message = exec("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/database.py 2>&1 '$image'");

    //echo($message);
    $response = 1;
}

if ($response == 0) {
    echo "not valid";
}
```

> Error:
>
> I/System.out: 
> **Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: 
>   Unsupported marker type 0xf1 in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/pythonconnect.php** on line **16**
> **Warning**:
>   imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'JPEG' format in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/pythonconnect.php** on line **16**
>   **Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/pythonconnect.php** on line **16**

Turning image into base64 in java:

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file){
        String encodedfile = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            encodedfile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodedfile;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code that was used to create the base64Encoded string from the JPEG

Comment: Can you show us that code

Comment: i've added it now

Comment: Dont think you need this line `$im = imageCreateFromString($content);`

Comment: I have updated the code, however it still doesn't allow me to open the file. It says it may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.